# Object to array convertion works as separate function but not as object method

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, dictionary

I json decoded API's  json data and wanted to convert the object  into array . I wrote a    class function to do that . And that function is

```
public function objectToArray($result) {
    if (is_object($result)) {
        $result = get_object_vars($result);
    }
    if (is_array($result)) {
        return array_map( @$this->objectToArray, $result);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $result;    
    }
}
```

So the above code didnt work . It only converted 'first layers' objects but not that objects array's object (I am talking about nested arrays and objects) . 
But when  I  declared that outside the class like function objectToArray and changed array_map's argument to 'objectToArry'  all of a sudden it started to work . How come ? Is there a problem with recurive function inside a class in PHP ?

Comment: Every time you use @ error suppression a kitten feels sad. Please think of the kittens.

Comment: You should not suppress errors (`@`). If you do, you might miss anything PHP wants to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use methods of objects as callbacks, you have to pass an array:

```
array_map(array($this, 'objectToArray'), $result);
```

PHP would have probably told you that, if you hadn't suppressed errors with the `@` operator.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
json_decode($input,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `$this->objectToArray` is a reference to a property of that name, not to the function as you expected it. You need to pass an array with the object instance and the method name:

```php
return array_map(array($this, 'objectToArray'), $result);
```